# save a list of references in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following schemas:

```
var TagSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  }
});

var SnippetSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },

  tags: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tag'
  }]
});
```

I create a new Snippet and search for a tag (got the tagid from the request) to add it to the list of tags.

```
var snippet = new Snippet(req.body);

Tag.findById(req.body.tagid).exec(function(err, tag) {
  snippet.tags.push(tag);
  snippet.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
    } else {
      res.json(snippet);
    }
  });
});
```

but i always get the following error:
**Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "tags"**

i tried the same thing with tags being a single tag instad of an array of tags - and that worked perfectly.

does anyone have an idea?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the error is caused by this line:

```
var snippet = new Snippet(req.body);
```

My guess would be that `req.body.tags` is an object and not an array of objects. When you subsequently save the snippet, the error is thrown.

<s>As a quick fix, you can wrap it with an array:</s>

```
var tags = req.body.tags;
if (tags && tags.constructor.name !== 'Array') {
  req.body.tags = [ tags ];
}
var snippet = new Snippet(req.body);
```

**EDIT**: @damphat correctly commented that Mongoose will try and convert non-array values to an array, if that's what's defined in the schema. However, you still need to make sure that the array that's being created is a valid one.

Comment: take me an hour, and I learn a lot of thing from this, but I still can not reproduce the error message :)

Comment: [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/7caefe365ca3da152145) that reproduces the error. I edited my answer because technically the issue occurs when you save the document.

Comment: @damphat (sorry, forgot to mention you in the previous comment)

Comment: ah, I just console.log(new Snippet({tags: "wrong value"}) and see {tag:[]}. Anyway, your quick fix is wrong with my test, I think you should check if tags is 24 hex or not instead of make it to be an array. Because mongoose will convert `tags='1123456789012345678901234'` to tags=[ObjectId('1123456789012345678901234')]

Comment: @damphat well, the *best* solution would be to have `req.body.tags` be in a proper format :) That's why I called it a 'quick fix' :)

Comment: @robertklep You basically were right. The problem was `new Snippet(req.body)`. This created a "corrupt" array of tags (even though it still had a constructor named 'Array'). I created and filled the snippet step by step `var snippet = new Snippet(); snippet.content = req.body.content; ...` Doing that it does not matter whether i push the whole tag to the array or just its id. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @robertklep and mongoose will convert to string to array by default, that 'quick fix' is unnecessary.